# Oracle sql query to xml

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, xml

I have the below query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PLAYERID, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME, P.POSITION,PT.POINTS, PT.MINUTES, CALC_TENDEX(P.PLAYERID, PT.TEAMID, 2009) TENDEX, T.DIVISION, PT.TEAMID, T.TEAMNAME
FROM PLAYERS P
JOIN PLAYERS_TEAMS PT ON P.PLAYERID = PT.PLAYERID
JOIN TEAMS T ON PT.TEAMID=T.TEAMID
WHERE PT.YEAR=2009 AND T.DIVISION='East'
ORDER BY TENDEX DESC
FETCH FIRST 12 ROWS ONLY;
```

I want to output this query as xml, with custom format like this:

```
<nba dataset="topplayers">
    <division ID="East">
        <player></player>
                .
                .
                .
        <player></player>
</nba>
```

I have tried using SQL/XML but whatever I try does not return answers I want. Is there some easy way to directly convert it to xml?

EDIT: SQL/XML I have tried (along with various alterations of this)

```
SELECT DISTINCT XMLELEMENT("nba",
         XMLAGG (
           XMLELEMENT("division",
             XMLATTRIBUTES(T.DIVISION AS "ID"),
               (SELECT DISTINCT XMLAGG(
               XMLELEMENT("player",
                 XMLFOREST(
                   P.PLAYERID AS "playerid",
                   P.FIRSTNAME AS "firstname",
                   P.LASTNAME AS "lastname",
                   P.POSITION AS "position",
                   PT.POINTS AS "points",
                   PT.MINUTES AS "minutes",
                   CALC_TENDEX(PT.PLAYERID, PT.TEAMID, 2009) AS "tindex",
                   T.DIVISION AS "division",
                   PT.TEAMID AS "teamid",
                   T.TEAMNAME AS "teamname"
                  )
                )
              )
              FROM PLAYERS P
              JOIN PLAYERS_TEAMS PT ON P.PLAYERID = PT.PLAYERID
              JOIN TEAMS T ON PT.TEAMID=T.TEAMID
              WHERE PT.YEAR=2009 AND T.DIVISION='East' AND ROWNUM < 12
            )
          )
        )
       ) AS "nba"
FROM TEAMS T
WHERE T.DIVISION = 'East';
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to convert SQL directly to XML, for example:

```
SQL> select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from hr.employees where employee_id = 100') 
       as xml from dual;

XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <EMPLOYEE_ID>100</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <FIRST_NAME>Steven</FIRST_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>King</LAST_NAME>
  <EMAIL>SKING</EMAIL>
  <PHONE_NUMBER>515.123.4567</PHONE_NUMBER>
  <HIRE_DATE>17-JUN-03</HIRE_DATE>
  <JOB_ID>AD_PRES</JOB_ID>
  <SALARY>24000</SALARY>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>90</DEPARTMENT_ID>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

If you have a fixed format of your XML, you can describe it in XSLT and use [XMLTRANSFORM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions270.htm#SQLRF06171) to take care of the rest.